# How to git mirror some specified branch I wanted

Tags: git

I'm using a repo that contains hundreds of branch(Because this repo is used by lots of products).
Such as:
$ git branch -a

remotes/origin/BranchA

remotes/origin/BranchB

remotes/origin/BranchC

remotes/origin/BranchD

......

But I just need a few branch(may be just Branch A, B) of this repo.
Is there any way I just mirror A and B from this repo?
Each time I used git branch on this mirrored repo, I always get confused, and it wastes lot of system resources.

This is a very commonly used repo in my company, lots of products are using it. So it has lot of different branches. But, I'm just work on some of these product(in fact still above 20 above products), I don't take care other branches, I just want to mirror mine. Could I just use git clone --mirror to mirror some branches I want?

Comment: I'm not convinced that just doing a vanilla flavored `git fetch` would be a waste of system resources of bad in any way.  It is likely that many of these branches share a common ancestor, and that fetching them all would be far less costly than you think.  I'd go with just doing a `git fetch` for all branches, unless you have a real performance reason not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may be beyond your power to make this happen, the *best* solution would be to put each product in its own repo.  What you have there sounds like what happens when someone versed in TFVC tries to use git without learning about git first.  I would expect this to cause additional problems besides just the one you're facing.

Since you probably just have to deal with it as it is, here is what you can do:

You can control the fetch refspec used by your clone.

```
git config remote.origin.fetch <refspec>
```

In the case where the branches are namespaced by product, this would be easy.  For example, if the repo has branches like

```
product_a/branch_1
product_a/branch_2
product_b/branch_1
...
```

then you could use a fetch refspect like `+refs/heads/product_a/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` for a repo that clones just `product_a`, or `+refs/heads/product_a/*:refs/remotes/origin/product_a/* +refs/heads/product_c/*:refs/remotes/origin/product_c/*` if you want to clone a couple products (though, again, I don't recommend the latter).

But I'm guessing the layout isn't that convenient, and you may have to specify the individual branches you want, e.g. `+refs/heads/branch_1:refs/remotes/origin/branch_1 +refs/heads/branch_3:refs/remotes/origin/branch_3 ...`.  The problem here is, if feature branches come and go, you have to manually add and remove them (or deal with them some other way).  So the cure may be worse than the disease.

Anyway, putting it all together, to create a clone for a product that uses a couple specific branches, you could say

```
git clone --single-branch -b branch_1 remote_repo_url my_product_A_repo
cd my_product_A_repo
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/branch_1:refs/remotes/origin/branch_1 +refs/heads/branch_3:refs/remotes/origin/branch_3 +refs/heads/branch_37:refs/remotes/origin/branch_37
git fetch
```